# How to set conditions for groups when grouped by several columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame grouped by atc, product_name, strength and form as shown in the attached screenshot. I would like the code to return groups where there are more than 1 unique substitution group.

[grouped DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpwia.png)

I have tried the below code but it also returns groups where there is only 1 unique group:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['atc','product_name','strength','form'])['substitution_group'].apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()) >= 2)]
```

Furthermore, the Groupby does not put identical names and strengths into one group but makes several. Is there a solution to this?